# Is there a way to bind input to value and track with different ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

This is my problem:

> - I'm using ng-repeat to create input fields from an array. [a, b, c,...]
> - I have a button that lets you add more blank input fields.
> - After clicking the save button I want to be able to create a new array from the input fields.

So I'm thinking of having an iterated `ng-model (item-1, item-2, item-3,...)` tracking each of these inputs, then iterate through them when I hit save. But that requires me to have each input binded with a new variable that's not from [a, b, c,....].

So what I'm asking is how I can do this pseudo code with AngularJS.

```
<input ng-repeat="letter in letters" 
  set-value="letter.value" 
  bind-to-model="someNewVariable">
```

Comment: *I have a button that lets you add more blank input fields*. Can you share the logic of this button?

Comment: When clicked it will call a function that creates a blank `<input ng-model=item-someIndex>` and insert it into the DOM.

Comment: And in this function you can also create `$scope.item-someIndex` and the model of this input will bind to this scope variable, isn't it?

Comment: I'm implicitly defining the variable when I do ng-model=item-someIndex. So yeah basically.

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

**Html :**

```
<div class="addcontend">
      <div ng-repeat="item in inputs track by $index">
        <input ng-model="inputs[$index]" ng-value="item" />
        <button ng-click='getVal(item)'>get input value</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addfield()">Add field</button>
  <button ng-click="log()">log</button>
```

**Controller :**

```
 app.controller('cntr',function($scope){
    $scope.inputs = ['a', 'b'];

    $scope.addfield = function(){
       $scope.inputs.push('')
    }

    $scope.getVal = function(v){
       alert(v);
    }

    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log($scope.inputs)
    }
 })
```